# Array of coordinates in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, coordinates

I have a class `Point` in Ruby like this:

```ruby
class Point

    attr_accessor :x,:y

    def initialize(*args)
        @y,@x=args
    end

end
```

How can I create an array of Point[1...n]? Thanks so much!

Comment: Arrays in Ruby, like many languages, are zero-indexed, so it'd be `Point[0..n-1]`.

Comment: @tadman: Sorry, I mean `Point[0..n-1]`, can you help me? thanks

Comment: I added an answer a while ago.

Answer (score 0):

Just create an array and put your points in there. Where are you running into trouble?

```
irb(main):008:0> p1 = Point.new(0,0)
=> #<Point:0x007fa671a56a08 @y=0, @x=0>
irb(main):010:0> p2 = Point.new(1,1)
=> #<Point:0x007fa6720f21c8 @y=1, @x=1>
irb(main):011:0> points = [p1,p2]
=> [#<Point:0x007fa671a56a08 @y=0, @x=0>, #<Point:0x007fa6720f21c8 @y=1, @x=1>]
```

Answer (score 0):

Given a constructor like that, it's pretty easy to convert from one structure to another:

```
[ [1,2], [3,4], [5,6] ].collect { |t| Point.new(*t) }
# => [#<Point:0x007f904a049ed0 @y=1, @x=2>, #<Point:0x007f904a049e58 @y=3, @x=4>, #<Point:0x007f904a049db8 @y=5, @x=6>]
```

Here `*t` represents the [splat operation](http://endofline.wordpress.com/2011/01/21/the-strange-ruby-splat/) on the original array, effectively passing in the arguments directly instead of as an array.

Answer (score 0):

As simple as:

```
(1..n).map { |i| Point.new(1, i) }
```

---

Full example:

```
class Point
    attr_accessor :x,:y

    def initialize(*args)
        @y,@x=args
    end
end
n = 10
array_of_coords = (1..n).map { |i| Point.new(1, i) }
```

Comment: Can you explain more, how can I init and use it?

Comment: Define the **n** variable, e.g. `n = 10`. That's it. That expression will return an array.

Comment: How about i? I still don't understand, please show me an example. Thanks!

Comment: Updated answer. You don't need to define **i**, the value will be passed to it by the `map()` call.